# Warning: fread() , fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php

I'm trying to integrate TinyMCE into my website and I can seem to figure out this error. I'm trying to open the data file and put on variable to send to the editor, Been trying awhile cant seem to get it but here is what I have.

**Error:**

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in C:\htdocs\phpdev.com\EditPage.php on line 2

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in C:\htdocs\phpdev.com\EditPage.php on line 4

```
// <!-- Get data for the editor and print -->
$Content = @fopen("Code/Content/" . $Page . ".inc", "r");
$LoadPageContent = fread($Content, filesize($LoadPageContent));
$LoadPageContent = htmlspecialchars($LoadPageContent);
fclose($Content);
```

Comment: Remove error suppression from `fopen` and you will get a better error message

Comment: fopen failed to open the file so fclose has nothing to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is what worked:**

```
$OriginalContent = "Code/System/Content/" . $Page . ".inc";

$PageContents = fopen($OriginalContent, "rb");
$LoadPageContent = fread($PageContents, filesize($OriginalContent));
$LoadPageContent = htmlspecialchars($LoadPageContent);
fclose($PageContents);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).